# Weighted sum of a series of values, weighted based on the scale of the error.

Tags: statistics, means, error-propagation

I need to find the value and error of a weighted sum of values all with their own respective error.

Say I have three data points:

$ x_1 = 7 \pm 1$
$ x_2 = 9 \pm 0.8$
$ x_3 = 10 \pm 0.7$

I need to find the mean of these values, weighted by the magnitude of their errors so that values with greater error have less weighting.

I have tried a couple of approaches but have gotten unreasonable answers. Searching the web, there seems to be a lot of noise and cannot find anything specifically that I am looking for.

My initial approach was to calculate in this manner:

$\bar{x} = \frac{\sum_i x_iw_i}{\sum_i w_i}$

For my example this gives:

$\bar{x} = \frac{7*(1)+ 9*(0.8) + 10*(0.7)}{1+0.8+0.7} = 8.48$

I know this is obviously incorrect as it gives greater weighting to the values with larger error. I'm struggling to work out a mathematically proper fix. Can I just take the inverse of the weighting?

Errors I can propagate trivially once I know how to calculate $\bar{x}$

Comment: So...what's stopping you?

Comment: @lulu Sorry for the lack of detail. I have added more.

Comment: It's still too vague.  There are lots of functions that decay to $0$ as the argument grows, it all depends on what you want and we can't tell you what you want.  I seriously doubt $\frac 1x$ is what you want, since that blows up near $0$ (so your sum would be entirely dominated by a single accurate datapoint).

Comment: If you want a quick fix multiplier, try $\exp(-x)$.  That is $1$ when $x=0$ and of course it decays to $0$.  Or try $\exp(-\lambda x)$ for some positive constant $\lambda $ (so you can "tune" the decay rate).

Comment: Note:  You only said you wanted the "weighted sum" but it appears from the trial computation you wrote that you meant to say that you wanted the "weighted average".  Again, we can't tell you what you want...you need to be clear about that at your end.

Comment: This is for a scientific data problem. I have a series of data points, and I need to find their average. If there was a value with an error of 0 it would be appropriate for that to be the value as that is the absolute value (if errors were calculated properly).

Comment: Well, as I say, it's whatever you want.  There isn't a "right" answer here.  Personally, I'd never use a weighting function that had a singularity (as the output will be wildly unstable), but you could use my exponential with a very large $\lambda$ to ensure that you really only capture the best data points.

Comment: For instance, what do you believe the best answer would be for your given data?  What's your feeling I mean.  If I take $\lambda=1$, I get $8.818$  If I take $\lambda=10$ I get $9.635$  Going the other way, if we take $\lambda = .1$ I get $8.68$ which is more or less the unweighted average.  How would you rank those values?

Comment: Please do *not* vandalise your post, especially if it has been answered. This is out of respect for the answerer and any future viewers of the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Chapter 7, "Weighted Averages" in *An Introduction to Error Analysis, Second Edition*, by John R. Taylor, the appropriate procedure is as follows.

Let's say your three values are $x_i \pm \sigma_i$ for $i=1,2,3$. Compute weights $w_i$ by
$$w_i = \frac{1}{\sigma_i^2}$$
Then your best estimate is the weighted average
$$x_{wav} = \frac{\sum w_i x_i}{\sum w_i}$$
The idea is that these weights minimize the variance of $x_{wav}$.